# Default Dynamic Documentation DXA module - not working

Tags: dxa, tridion-docs, dxd-11.1

I am trying to setup the default dynamic documentation module with DXA 2.2 (Docs 14 SP1) using the Velu's [instructions](http://2019.tridiondevelopersummit.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/DXA-2.2-Dynamic-Documentation-Module-Presentation-TDS-2019.pdf) and the [custom web application](https://github.com/sdl/dd-webapp-custom-examples), since NPM was failing based on the instructions provided earlier. Build is successful but the page does not come up. I have verified via PCA client that the publications and pages are available.

I am unable to retrieve the contents of the page using the default application. I get the following WARNING in the logs.

`http://localhost:91/system/assets/gui/assets/stylesheets/main.css?4fb2ffd7-2384-4928-8741-59d2ca17aa70' maps to Localization []
2020-04-07 16:19:26,122 [6] DEBUG - Request URL 'http://localhost:91/system/assets/gui/assets/main.bundle.js?4fb2ffd7-2384-4928-8741-59d2ca17aa70' maps to Localization []
2020-04-07 16:19:26,123 [5] DEBUG - Request URL 'http://localhost:91/system/assets/gui/assets/vendor.bundle.js?4fb2ffd7-2384-4928-8741-59d2ca17aa70' maps to Localization []
2020-04-07 16:19:26,140 [7] WARN  - Item 'Invalid publication id '' stored in localization.' not found. Sending HTTP 404 (Not Found) response.
2020-04-07 16:19:26,631 [6] WARN  - Item 'Invalid publication id '' stored in localization.' not found. Sending HTTP 404 (Not Found) response.
2020-04-07 16:19:27,132 [5] WARN  - Item 'Invalid publication id '' stored in localization.' not found. Sending HTTP 404 (Not Found) response.
2020-04-07 16:19:30,188 [16] DEBUG - Request URL 'http://localhost:91/system/assets/gui/assets/stylesheets/main.css?4fb2ffd7-2384-4928-8741-59d2ca17aa70' maps to Localization []
2020-04-07 16:19:30,198 [16] WARN  - Item 'Invalid publication id '' stored in localization.' not found. Sending HTTP 404 (Not Found) response.
2020-04-07 16:19:47,992 [5] DEBUG - Request URL 'http://localhost:91/system/assets/gui/assets/favicon.ico' maps to Localization []
2020-04-07 16:19:48,007 [5] WARN  - Item 'Invalid publication id '' stored in localization.' not found. Sending HTTP 404 (Not Found) response.`

In the console, I get the following exception as well

[image]

I am unable to see the definition of the default model for the page but able to notice the page / region mapping is generated in the dynamic documentation module [default mapping to main region]. Can this be extended?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the NPM dependencies were not resolved correctly. The documentation is misleading online. I was able to manually resolve the dependencies and packages.

I will add a comment to update SDL documentation and Velu's blog as well.